# Mysql how to filter results on multiple rows by 2 queries

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to filter results where the relation is in multiple rows and so I need to first get the ID by matching a value and then use the query again to fetch value from another row for the retrieved value from the same table.

```
ID - MetaKey - MetaValue
142398 - _wc_checkout_add_on_id - 4
142398 - _wc_checkout_add_on_value - wife
142398 - _wc_checkout_add_on_label - Wife
```

So I get ID via matching key and value from row 1, now within the same query I want to get metavalue of 2nd and 3rd row to generate the final results, I am unable to do so at the moment.

Can anyone suggest please?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with sub query, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id IN (
 SELECT id FROM table WHERE metaKey = ? AND metaValue = ?
);
```

This will give you all the records belonging to that id. Now, if you don't want the first row in the result then you ca exclude itm, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id IN (
 SELECT id FROM table WHERE metaKey = ? AND metaValue = ?
)
AND metaKey <> ? AND metaValue <> ?;
```

Comment: the result also include ROW1

Comment: that's not mentioned in the question (i.e. whether first row needs to be excluded), I have added another query to exlude it anyway.

Comment: I have as well :)

Comment: Thanks Guys, so I tried the query as followed  SELECT *
FROM `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta`
WHERE `order_item_id` IN (
 SELECT `order_item_id` FROM `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` WHERE `meta_key` like '_wc_checkout_add_on_id' AND `meta_value` = '2'
)   But it still gives me random results and not the same particular values?

Comment: Results generated by above query : 813107
142396 - _wc_checkout_add_on_id - 2
142396 - _wc_checkout_add_on_value - 1
142396 - _wc_checkout_add_on_label
142402 - _tax_class - 0

Comment: Could you add some sample records in the qustion?

Answer (score 1):

something like this will work:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM yourTAble t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2 
  ON t1.id = t2.id 
  AND NOT t2.MetaKey = t1.MetaKey
WHERE t1.id = 142398;
```